# How to do validation on visual force page

Tags: visualforce, validation

here i am trying to do validation here but i don't know how to do that on the following vf page-
[image]

```
Validations: 
a.  If Product Type is New, please populate the Service Start Date and the Full Revenue Date.
b.  If Product Type is a Renewal, please populate the Previous Monthly Revenue (ensure it is greater than 0) and the Full Revenue Date.
c.  Ensure Contract Start Date <= Service Start Date <= Full Revenue Date
```

but since here i am using wrapper class so how to fetch these details and do validation can anyone plz help me out.

vf page--

```
<apex:page tabStyle="Opportunity" controller="GEN_ProductSelectionController" >
 <script>
 function computeTotal(){
    var quantity = document.getElementById(Quantity).value;    
    var price = document.getElementById(Price).value;        
    var totalprice;
    totalprice = quantity*Price;        
    document.getElementById(TotalPrice).value = totalprice;
  }
</script>

 <apex:form >
 <apex:pageBlock >
 <apex:pageBlockButtons Location="Top" >
         <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!Save}"/>
         <apex:commandButton value="Delete" action="{!Deletes}"/>
     </apex:pageBlockButtons>
  <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Wrapper}" var="wrap" >
   <apex:column value="{!wrap.selProd.Name}" headerValue="Product Name"/>
    <apex:column value="{!wrap.selProd.UnitPrice}" id="Price" headerValue="Price"/>
    <apex:column headerValue="Type">
    <apex:inputField id="Type" value="{!wrap.oppLineItem.Type__c}"  />
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Quantity">
    <apex:inputField id="Quantity" value="{!wrap.oppLineItem.Quantity}"  />
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Monthly Revenue">
    <apex:inputField value="{!wrap.oppLineItem.Monthly_Revenue__c}"/>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Contract Start Date">
    <apex:inputField value="{!wrap.oppLineItem.Contract_Start_Date__c}"/>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Full Revenue Date">
    <apex:inputField value="{!wrap.oppLineItem.Full_Revenue_Date__c}"/>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Service Start Date">
    <apex:inputField value="{!wrap.oppLineItem.Service_Start_Date__c}"/>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="TotalPrice">
    <apex:inputField id="TotalPrice" value="{!wrap.oppLineItem.TotalPrice}" onblur="computeTotal();" />
    </apex:column>                         
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller--

```
public class GEN_ProductSelectionController {

         ID objCurrentOppId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');    

         Public List<OpportunityLineItem> opportunityLineItemList{get;set;}
         public List<wrapOpportunityLineItem> wrapper{get;set;}
         public List<wrapProduct> wrapProductList {get; set;} //Used for Search button
         public List<PricebookEntry> selectedProducts{get;set;}
         public List<OpportunityLineItem> closeProduct{get;set;}
         public String searchstring {get;set;}      

         //Display the products already available
         public GEN_ProductSelectionController(){
                 wrapProductList = new List<wrapProduct>();

                 for(PricebookEntry priceBookEntryObject: [select Id, Name,ProductCode,UnitPrice,product2.Type__c from PricebookEntry]) {
                 wrapProductList.add(new wrapProduct(priceBookEntryObject));
                 }
         }

         //Displays search result
         public void search(){  
                 wrapProductList = new List<wrapProduct>();
                 string searchquery='select name,id,Product2Id,ProductCode,UnitPrice,product2.Type__c from PricebookEntry where name like \'%'+searchstring+'%\' Limit 20';  

                 for(PricebookEntry priceBookEntryObject: Database.query(searchquery)) {
                      wrapProductList.add(new wrapProduct(priceBookEntryObject)); //adding the searched products into list
                 }
        }  

        //Select button funtion
        public PageReference selectProduct() {
                selectedProducts = new List<PricebookEntry>();

                for(wrapProduct wrapProductObj : wrapProductList) {
                     if(wrapProductObj.selected == true) {
                      selectedProducts.add(wrapProductObj.productObject);
                     }
                }

                system.debug('selectedWrapperList size ---------'+selectedProducts.size());
                PageReference pagePrice = new PageReference('/apex/GEN_MultiEdit?id='+objCurrentOppId);
                opportunityLineItemList = [Select Quantity,UnitPrice,TotalPrice,Type__c,Monthly_Revenue__c,Contract_Start_Date__c,Full_Revenue_Date__c,Service_Start_Date__c,OpportunityId, Product_UK__c from OpportunityLineItem ];
                wrapper = new List<wrapOpportunityLineItem>();

                for(Integer i=0; i<selectedProducts.size(); i++) {
                      // Pass new OLI with opportunity id
                      wrapper.add(new wrapOpportunityLineItem(new OpportunityLineItem(OpportunityId = objCurrentOppId,Product_UK__c = objCurrentOppId,PricebookEntryId = selectedProducts[i].Id),
                                           selectedProducts[i]) );
                }

                pageprice.setRedirect(false);
                return pageprice; 
        } 


        public PageReference Deletes() {
               PageReference pagecancel = new PageReference('https://ap2.salesforce.com/006/o');
               pagecancel.setRedirect(true);
               return pageCancel;
        }

        public PageReference save(){
                 List<OpportunityLineItem> oliList = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();

                for(wrapOpportunityLineItem wrapOLIObj :wrapper){
                  oliList.add(wrapOLIObj.oppLineItem);
                }

                  insert oliList;
                  PageReference pagecancel = new PageReference('https://ap2.salesforce.com/006/o');
                  pagecancel.setRedirect(true);
                  return pageCancel;
        } 

        //Cancel button code     
        public PageReference Cancel() {
                PageReference opportunityRecordPage = new PageReference('https://ap2.salesforce.com/006/o');
                opportunityRecordPage.setRedirect(true);
                return opportunityRecordPage; 
        }


        //First page wrapper class
        public class wrapProduct {
                public PricebookEntry productObject {get; set;}
                public Boolean selected {get; set;}

                public wrapProduct(PricebookEntry pBEParam) {
                    productObject = pBEParam;
                    selected = false;
                }
        }

        //Wrapper class for Gen_MultiEdit Page
        public class wrapOpportunityLineItem{

                public OpportunityLineItem oppLineItem{get;set;}
                public PricebookEntry selProd{get;set;}

                public wrapOpportunityLineItem(OpportunityLineItem oli, PricebookEntry sp)
                {  

                    oppLineItem = oli;
                    selProd = sp;
                }

        }


    }
```

Comment: Or simply way create validation rule in your custom object. When you try to insert/update the record those validation record will be fire and user will get error.

Answer (score 1):

You have a choice: visualforce validation or (additionally) apex validation. The second one is more reasonable if the validation is critical in your app.

**Visualforce**: 
There is an `required` attribute available for the [`apex:inputField`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputField.htm) It will do the whole job for you together with functions.

The validation of the "Service Start Date" depending on the value of the "Type" picklist could looks like this:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!wrap.oppLineItem.Service_Start_Date__c}" 
                 required="{!ISPICKVAL(wrap.oppLineItem.Type__c, 'New')}" />
```

Additionally you will need a little "trigger" that will evaluate the formula every time the user selects another value in the type picklist. It could be done by re-render the table after the type-value has beed changed:

```
<apex:form>
...
<!-- This function will be called every time the type-value is changed -->
<apex:actionFunction name="refreshBlock" reRender="myBlock" />
...
<!-- This block will be re-rendered every type the type-value is changed -->
<!-- Thereby the formulas are re-evaluated and required attributes are set correctly -->
<apex:pageBlock id="myBlock">
...
<apex:inputField id="Type" 
                 value="{!wrap.oppLineItem.Type__c}"
                 onchange="refreshBlock();"/>
```

**Apex validation**: 
Sometimes (or better say always) it is reasonable to do server-side validation. For that you will need a Page Message to display a warnings to the user and some Apex logic for validation of the user inputs:

Page:

```
<apex:pageBlock id="myBlock">
    <apex:pageMessages />
    ...
```

Apex class method:

```
public PageReference save(){

    List<OpportunityLineItem> oliList = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();

    // Some variable to be able to track errors 
    Boolean isError = false;

    for(wrapOpportunityLineItem wrapOLIObj :wrapper){

        // Validation logic starts here
        if(wrapOLIObj.oppLineItem.Type__c == 'New' && oppLineItem.Service_Start_Date__c == null){
            isError = true;
        }

        oliList.add(wrapOLIObj.oppLineItem);
    }

    // If there was any errors - display a message to the user and return null
    if(isError){
        ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.WARNING, 'Please fill out all mandatory fields!');
        ApexPages.addMessage(msg);
    }
    // If no errors - continue to process the code 
    else{
        insert oliList;
        PageReference pagecancel = new PageReference('https://ap2.salesforce.com/006/o');
        pagecancel.setRedirect(true);
        return pageCancel;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: getting this error-- Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'ISPICKVAL()'. Expected Picklist, received Text

Comment: @RAT__ Is not a picklist? Then use `required="{!wrap.oppLineItem.Type__c == 'New'}"`

Comment: actually it's a picklist,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, okay i'll try this also